# Mark resource to be replaced alongside the resource it depends on

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I am currently at a loss on how I am supposed to handle this with terraform.

I have started writing a module to create a database instance for a service (extremly simplified version below)

```
# main.tf
resource "google_sql_database_instance" "database_instance" {
  database_version    = "POSTGRES_14"
  deletion_protection = false
  instance_type       = "CLOUD_SQL_INSTANCE"
  name                = "test-database"
  project             = var.project_name
  region              = "europe-west3"
  root_password       = null
  settings {
    activation_policy     = "ALWAYS"
    availability_type     = "ZONAL"
    collation             = null
    connector_enforcement = "NOT_REQUIRED"
    disk_autoresize       = true
    disk_autoresize_limit = 0
    disk_type             = "PD_SSD"
    edition               = "ENTERPRISE"
    pricing_plan          = "PER_USE"
    tier                  = "db-custom-1-3840"
    time_zone             = null
    maintenance_window {
      day          = 1
      hour         = 0
      update_track = "stable"
    }
  }
  timeouts {
    create = null
    delete = null
    update = null
  }
}

resource "google_sql_database" "database" {
  instance   = google_sql_database_instance.database_instance.name
  name       = "new_database"
  project    = var.project_name
  depends_on = [google_sql_database_instance.database_instance]
}
```

When `terraform apply`ing the first time, the database instance and database are created, with the instance created in europe-west3.

However, I changed my mind and want to have the instance in `europe-west1`

It's not hard for the instance, I just have to change the parameter and `terraform plan` tells me that the instance will be replaced.

However, no mention is made of the database, which is kept unchanged in the state.

But once the database instance is recreated, the database "new_database" does not appear in the "test-database" instance.

When rerunning `terraform apply`, it indeed shows that the database needs to be created, and does so without issue.

However, it's a bit annoying having to run `terraform apply` twice, is there something I could specify in my `main.tf` so that the database is destroyed then recreated in one single step ?

Comment: Since you are using the implicit dependency already, there is no need for the `depends_on` meta-argument. However, what you could try is using lifecycle [`create_before_destroy`](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/meta-arguments/lifecycle#create_before_destroy) argument.

Comment: Sadly, this does not seem to work. There is still no mention of replacing the database, and the database instance creation seems to run indefinitely (which is probably a bug)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like there's a hidden¹ constraint between `google_sql_database_instance` and `google_sql_database` whereby deleting the database instance implicitly deletes the database. Since Terraform doesn't know to expect that situation, it instead understands the database has having been "deleted outside of Terraform" and needs to recover on the next plan/apply round.

Although ideally Terraform would be able to detect situations like this itself, these inter-resource constraints are not currently part of Terraform's model and so it takes a little extra configuration wiring to help Terraform understand what's going on:

```
resource "google_sql_database" "database" {
  instance   = google_sql_database_instance.database_instance.name
  name       = "new_database"
  project    = var.project_name

  lifecycle {
    replace_triggered_by = [
      google_sql_database_instance.database_instance.region,
    ]
  }
}
```

This [`replace_triggered_by`](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/meta-arguments/lifecycle#replace_triggered_by) hint tells Terraform that if `google_sql_database_instance.database_instance.region` has any pending changes then it should plan to replace `google_sql_database.database`.

If there are any other arguments of `google_sql_database_instance` that would cause it to get replaced if changed, and if you expect to need to change those arguments in future, you can list those in the `replace_triggered_by` argument too.

Although Terraform does allow assigning the whole `google_sql_database_instance.database_instance` resource in `replace_triggered_by`, I would not recommend that in this case because it means that Terraform will assume it needs to replace the database if *anything* changes about the database instance, which I expect is too strong a constraint for the situation you're describing.

---

¹ "hidden" in the sense that Terraform doesn't know about it